# Sitecore:Separate Data and DataBases folder from Inetpub using SIM

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I m using Sitecore instance manager for installing new instances in the developer machine. And all 3 the folder Data,Databases and website are saving in the location I given in SIM(d:\inetpub\wwwroot[sitename]). 
Is there any way that I can specify all the  folders in  different places using SIM itself.
EG:

```
Website=>d:\inetpub\wwwroot\[sitename]\website
    Data=>d:\Data\[sitename]\Data
    Databases=>d:\Databases\[sitename]\Databases
    Logs=>d:\Logs\[sitename]\logs
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: It is not possible to specify it in configurations. However SIM is open-source application, so you can modify sources and have your own version of SIM, where it is possible.

Comment: FWIW - this is the same behavior of the default install done by the Sitecore installer (though, yes, you can change these paths during the install wizard). SIM itself was designed original for support staff to replicate environments. As Anton noted, it is an open source project, and I'm sure a PR adding the functionality would be welcome.